# Our outgoing emails from a shared hosting provider (Bluehost) are returned because the server is listed as SPAM SERVERS

Tags: email, spam, email-bounces

I am getting very frustrated with this web hosting provider -- [Bluehost.com](http://www.bluehost.com/). We have several small business sites hosted with them. We also use email accounts provided by the Bluehost for our outgoing and incoming mail. Recently we've started receiving a lot of bounced emails back with messages as such:

> Your e-mail was not delivered to the recipient because of bad
>   reputation of its server sending the e-mail. For more information
>   contact the administrator of your server of the SMTP.

Note that we do not send out any unsolicited emails.

I sent several support tickets to Bluehost and has not yet received a meaningful reply.

I'm curious, what is the way to send out emails in this case -- still preserving our email address: name@oursite.com?

Comment: This is a result of you and many others sharing the same mail server with all your different domains. There are spammers among those others. Those spammers could even be CLAIMING to be sending mail from your domain, and there would be no way to know the difference between you and the spammer. Once the IP address(es) and network get a reputation for spam that isn't soon stopped, the IP addresses get the reputation as "spammy" so users of these lists of addresses can just summarily refuse all email from them.

Comment: @Skaperen: Good info, thanks. I thought so and you confirmed it. So besides using Google Apps, as was suggested below, is there any way for us to keep our email address and send out mail that doesn't bounce?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a reputable e-mail provider. I've had a lot of success with Google Apps.

In terms of the technical aspects, assuming Bluehost provide your DNS you would simply re-point your MX records to your new provider.

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I sign up for Google Apps, can I still use our email address? Example: name@oursite.com

Comment: You can :) Register for google apps with your oursite.com domain and point the oursite.com MX records to the destination Google give you. You can then register name@ accounts.